# How to count the amount of a specific set of characters (in an array) with JS (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, counting

**How to count the amount of a specific set of characters (in an array) with JS (javascript)?**

 The answer to the question can be found below in the comments! You don't need to read the context explained in my question.

**My specific context:** 
I got the idea to create a random password generator.
I succeeded in this. 
I have 4 arrays with numbers (1-9), uppercase (A-Z), lowercase (a-z) and special characters (!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,<,>,?). 
Multiple functions create the sting: randomPassword. They have a var that counts how many characters of that category are inside the password.

I've now made a feature so the user can specify the number of letters, numbers and special characters the user wants in the password.

When the user requests a password longer than those amounts combined, the rest of the password gets filled up with random characters. However, the amount of characters in each category doesn't match up anymore, because a different function is used.
I still want to display how many of each category are in the password. How could I make that work?

Thanks a lot!

*I have removed the code block that I originally shared because it is too context-specific and not necessary to answer the general question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was really big I was not able to check... see if this is what you need:

I am using regular expressions (this is a cool thing you can learn later)

```
function countLowerCaseLetters(input) {
    return input.length - input.replace(/[a-z]/g, '').length;
}

function countUpperCaseLetters(input) {
    return input.length - input.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '').length;
}

function countNumbers(input) {
    return input.length - input.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').length;
}

function countSpecialChars(input) {
    return input.length - input.replace(/[!@#$%^&*<>?]/g, '').length;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding! I'm going to call it a day, but I'll come back tomorrow to try it out! Again, thanks for responding!